# Wait for signal to start generating data from another process in python

Tags: python, signals, ipc

I have two independent processes in python: **producer** and **consumer**. Producer generates files and consumer does some processing on files.

To test both applications, I find myself constantly starting two programs, and producer has a delay function, etc. which is a pain.

What is the quickest way to implement some kind of signaling machinery in python so that **consumer** says "GO!" and **producer** starts doing things it does.

This way I can have producer running all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this (you didn't mention what platform(s) you care about, so I'll assume you want something cross-platform) is a UDP socket with a known port. If the consumer just listens on localhost port 12345, it can block on a `sock.recvfrom` call every time it needs to wait, and the producer can do a `sock.sendto` to notify it.

For example, here's a consumer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 12345))

while True:
    dummy, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    # work on files until done
```

And a producer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

for thing in things:
    # produce files for consumer
    sock.sendto(b'X', ('127.0.0.1', 12345))
```

Other things to consider:

- On Unix, there are advantages to using Unix sockets instead of UDP sockets.
- On Windows, there are advantages to using named pipes instead of sockets.
- You may want to make the consumer a [daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) (with or without a built-in "service" tool to start and stop it) on Unix or a Windows service on Windows. (You can even merge the service tool into the producer, so, e.g., the default behavior is to start a consumer if one isn't there, then shut it down when it's done, but it can also be used to launch a long-running consumer in the background.)
- You can extend this pretty easily to send more than just an empty notification—e.g., send a different message if you're done producing.

Comment: Nice. probably indeed the quickest implementation for IPC in python. This technique is mentioned in "Unix Network Programming" as well, but its examples are in C.

Comment: For something more heavyweight than what is suggested here you will probably need to explore an Advanced Message Queue Protocol like rabbitMQ or even something like Amazon Simple Queue Service.

Comment: @Dan: Agreed, for something actually heavyweight, you probably want something like Rabbit. But for intermediate cases, there's something to be said for sticking with a protocol a human tester can trivially netcat at the consumer…

Comment: @Dan: For your other comment, that book was pretty much the only way to learn about practical IPC back in the early 90s, so that must be where I got the idea originally. :) But does it really suggest UDP sockets with a known port, instead of Unix sockets with a known name? (I could dig up my copy, but you presumably have yours handy, or at least fresher in your memory.)

Comment: @abernert I only own the first volume of Unix Network Programming, which focus's on the the sockets. The real details of IPC are in volume 2, so I'm not sure of the author's implementation. However, in Volume 1 the author does mention IPC through sockets as a valid and "interesting" use of sockets. I hope the reference wasn't off-topic. I merely brought it up to back you up :)

Comment: @Dan: Not at all off-topic; any chance to let novices know about that book is probably a good chance to take. In most cases, it gives great explanations of why the design makes sense, and mentions any tradeoffs, and so on, in much better detail than any StackOverflow answer can.

Comment: @abernert +1 for netcat at the consumer.